# Google App Engine + Maven + JSP compilation

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven, intellij-idea

How do I get .jsp/.xhtml/.html files to trigger a compile/package goal in a Google App Engine + Maven + Eclipse setup? (actually it's the same for IntelliJ & Netbeans)

The .java files cause a compile goal just fine, which causes the target directory to update, which is then picked up by appengine:devserver, but nothing else works.

I've seen lots of people asking this, but no solution.

I'm using the simple GuestBook Maven archetype:

> mvn archetype:generate -Dappengine-version=1.9.15
>   -Dapplication-id=your-app-id -Dfilter=com.google.appengine.archetypes:guestbook-archetype

Followed by:

> mvn appengine:devserver

Eclipse Juno is setup to "build automatically", so touching a java file triggers the goal, just nothing else.

Frustrated!

**UPDATE**: I'm using the [GPE](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/) for Juno EE.

-- shane

Answer (score 0):

If you install the [GPE](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/), you can run from within the eclipse IDE. When running in debug mode, jsp and java file changes will get hot-loaded. You can also use the [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) plugin for eclipse to save time on redeploys/restarts.

EDIT:
If you're still having trouble, ensure that you have the m2e-wtp plugin installed into your eclipse, it enables a bunch of secret sauce. m2e is now intrinsic, i'm not sure about m2e-wtp. If I look in 'About' for eclipse, I can see a button for wtp. [m2e-wtp](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/)

For the record, this is actually unnecessarily hard. But once it works, it works.

Comment: Actually, I should have mentioned, I'm already using the GPE in Juno EE. It doesn't pick up the changes... I'd rather use an official Google project than JRebel, so if I'm doing something wrong with

Comment: I don't think Google has an official plugin that does what JRebel does for GAE. You can always try it out.

Comment: It really seems like something isn't setup properly. Surely I can't be the only person with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I feel there should be a better way, but this is a workaround:

Project -> Properties -> Builders

Click "New…" to create a builder that will invoke the mvn binary.

Here's my settings for it.

Location: /usr/local/bin/mvn
Working directory: ${workspace_loc:/}  (use browse workspace to populate this)
Arguments: -Dmaven.test.skip=true prepare-package war:exploded (these arguments seem to be the fastest way to produce the exploded war, ~1 second in my case)

In Build Options, deselect "Allocate Console" and select "Launch in background".

Except the 1 second delay, this works flawlessly for me.